# Trouble assigning value to integers inside a function to be referred to later - scope issue - I think

Tags: c#

I'm learning C#. (6 hours in) I'm more comfortable with Ruby and Javascript and am finding C# fun, yet way tighter in what it will allow you to do, so I am rediscovering simple functions. I'm trying to build a simple calculator just to transition to the C# way of doing things and I keep hitting scope issues.

Here's the code. The NumSelect function is breaking it. I want a user to be able to type in 2 numbers in the console and then they'll be added. Once that works I'll create other math operations and throw in some logic to have the user select with operation they would like to do and then ask them for their inputs and then do the calculation.

The error is

```
calculator.cs(18,9): error CS0103: The name `number1' does not exist in the current context
```

and it's hitting it at very instance of number1 and number2 beyond the NumSelector function. So it seems like a scope issue, but I can't figure out the right approach for assigning these variables in a function so I only have to do it once.

```
using System;

class SimpleMath
{
    public int Add(int number1, int number2)
    {
        int result = number1 + number2;
        return result;
    }
    public int Subtract(int number1, int number2)
    {
        int result = number1 - number2;
        return result;
    }
    //this function will assign the inputs to variables
    public int NumSelect()
    {
        number1 = Console.ReadLine;
        number2 = Console.ReadLine;
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        SimpleMath operation = new SimpleMath();

        Console.WriteLine("Give me two numbers and I will add them");
        operation.NumSelect();
        int result = operation.Add(number1, number2);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", number1, number2, result);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you need to decide whether these numbers are meant to be part of the state of your object or not. If they are, make them fields. If they're not, don't. In this case, I'd probably keep them as local variables and change your `NumSelect` code to simply return *one* number entered by the user - and call it twice:

```
public int NumSelect()
{
    string line = Console.ReadLine();
    return int.Parse(line);
}

static void Main()
{
    SimpleMath operation = new SimpleMath();

    Console.WriteLine("Give me two numbers and I will add them");
    int number1 = operation.NumSelect();
    int number2 = operation.NumSelect();
    int result = operation.Add(number1, number2);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", number1, number2, result);
}
```

You *could* change your whole class to make the values fields, and remove the parameters, like this:

```
class SimpleMath
{
    private int number1;
    private int number2;

    public int Add()
    {
        int result = number1 + number2;
        return result;
    }

    public int Subtract()
    {
        int result = number1 - number2;
        return result;
    }

    public int SelectNumbers()
    {
        number1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        number2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        SimpleMath operation = new SimpleMath();

        Console.WriteLine("Give me two numbers and I will add them");
        operation.NumSelect();
        int result = operation.Add();
        Console.WriteLine(
            "{0} + {1} = {2}",
            operation.number1,
            operation.number2,
            result);   
    }
}
```

This *doesn't* feel like the best approach to me - I'd take the earlier approach of using local variables in `Main` - but I wanted to show you the alternative. Note that you can only access `operation.number1` in `Main` because the `Main` method is in the same type - that should raise warning bells for you.

Comment: What's the point of taking the line in as a string? Why not just do
    int input = Console.ReadLine();
    return input;
I would guess you parse a string to handle poor input by users that's not an integer?
Thanks!

Comment: @nwimmer123: Did you try it? What's the declared return type of `Console.ReadLine()`? Is there an implicit conversion from that to `int`?

Comment: Interesting. Apparently all ReadLines are strings. Thus you can not save it as an integer assigned variable and must change its data type to do so. Crazy. The rigidity of C# takes some getting accustomed to after the looseness of Ruby.

Comment: @nwimmer123: You may think that's crazy, I think that just changing types dynamically without anything to stop you from doing the wrong thing is crazy :) Hopefully you'll come to love the benefits of static typing...

Comment: I'm coming to appreciate it. I liked learning in Ruby as it was more forgiving but when actually developing apps, the strictness is kinda nice.

Answer (score 1):

Put your two numbers as `class` fields rather than methods'.

```
int number1 = 0, number2 = 0; //have them as class fields like this
public int NumSelect()
{
    number1 = Console.ReadLine();
    number2 = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This way, you could access your `number1` and `number2` across different methods.

Method's fields/arguments are only valid *within* the method:

```
//number1 and number2 are method arguments, only accessible in the method
public int Add(int number1, int number2)
{ 
    int result = number1 + number2;
    return result;
}

//not accessible elsewhere
public int NumSelect() //number1 and number2 are unknown in this method
{
    number1 = Console.ReadLine();
    number2 = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Ahh, I thought if you made the method public, that all the variables would also be public and hence visible to the class. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just take two simple input from user in `Main()`. Like:

```
number1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

number2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

And then send it to your method Like:

```
int result = operation.Add(number1, number2);
```

otherwise declare the variables in the Field so that you can use them anywhere in the class.